NextJS exporting multiple middlewares
i need to export multiple middlewares in my middleware.js file but i get error A module cannot have multiple default exports., how to solve it ?
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { routing } from "./i18n/routing";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";


export default createMiddleware(routing);
export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ["/", "/(en|ar)/:path*"],
};



i tried to solve the issue by removing the default keyword and then assign them to variable and export them:
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { routing } from "./i18n/routing";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware(routing);
const authMiddleware = NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export { intlMiddleware, authMiddleware };

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)"],
};


but this will give error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring'), i guess the error comes from next-intl and its required to export createMiddleware(routing) as default

You can't have multiple default exports, just remove the default keyword.

This question is similar to: What is "export default" in JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Jean-SamuelGirard if i remove the default keyword i need to store them in a variable, for example const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware(routing);, but this will give error, i think it needs the createMiddleware(routing) to be exported by default, i don't know how to solve this issue, please check my post after edit

After reviewing the question, I believe it's a duplicate of How to use multiple middlewares in Next.js using the middleware.ts file?
Sorry for the misunderstanding. Essentially Next.js doesn't support exporting multiple middlewares so you'll need to combine them before exporting. The accepted answer of the question I linked is in Typescript, but it's easily changed for javascript by removing type indicators.

here is also a nicer way to do it https://medium.com/@tanzimhossain2/implementing-multiple-middleware-in-next-js-combining-nextauth-and-internationalization-28d5435d3187
